# Consulta sobre hosting DNS

Tags: hosting, dns, redes

No se si puedo consultar esto? Soy de argentina, y resulta que compre mi dominio en esta entidad NIC, donde solo registras el dominio .com.ar. Pero no tiene hosting dns.

El asunto es que tengo IP Fija contratada , y tengo el servidor web fisico en mi casa. Me resultaba mas economico.

Entonces me puse a instalar el server DNS yo mismo BIND9. Soy estudiante por lo tanto ignoro miles de cosas. Estube dias probandolo e intentando hacerlo funcionar en un Linux debian desde ssh. Pero despues del 4 dias intentando y probando me di cuenta que mi proveedor me reestringe desde otra NAT, el puerto 53 dns entrante. Asi que por mas que abra los puertos en mi router con ip fija, no puedo recibir peticiones dns entrantes. Los demas si los tengo habilitados.

Entonces quede colgado con el hosting dns, y no se donde puedo hostearlo. O si puedo buscar otra manera de hostear yo el dns.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esto es un problema de configuracion de redes, y no tengo muy claro que este sea el sitio donde vas a encontrar una respuesta. si tenes ip fija, no tenes que decirle a nic.ar que apunte ahi?

Comment: Buenas jaja si me imagine. Ultimamente me di cuenta que preciso de unirme a una comunidad o pedir asesoria . Porque uno no puede hacer todo solo. Jaja. Pero no. Esta entidad solo registra los dominios pero no hostea los servidores de resolucion de nombres. Dns es un lio. Jamas pense que seria tan complicado. Entonces intente montarme el server yo mismo. Y en local todo correcto. Pero al exterior no sale. Por lo tanto no permite la propagacion. Ddebere pagar. Pero la verdad de tanto y tanto renegar por dias ya me quitaron las ganas la verdas. De todas formas. Gracias

Comment: Aclaro q no sale al exterior porque revise los puertos  con nmap en debian y los puertos estan cerrados. A pesar de que tengo todo el control del router q me dio movistar. El bloqueo viene de afuera. En si inclusive la ip debe ser solamente fija y no publica. Ellos deben hacer algun toqueteo para q tengas acceso a varios puertos . Pero ip publica propia no es. Estube dias y dias toqueteando iptables, configurando bind, para despues dar una pasada con nmap y ver q el puerto es bloqueado. Asi nque bueno.Gracias.

Comment: Veo muy extraño tener IP fija con puertos bloqueados, deberías llamar a la compañía.  Un dato: El DNS no tiene por qué estar en tu servidor, cualquier servicio de DNS te sirve a tus propósitos, la mayoría de los hosting incluyen este servicio, por lo que si tienes un amigo que tenga contratado uno, puedes pedirle a él que agregue las entradas. Quizás haya un hosting gratuito que de ese servicio (000webhost lo hacía antes hoy ni idea)

Comment: Parece algo común en movistar.  Mírate este hilo donde hablan de ello y donde parece que abren el puerto pero debes pedirlo de forma expresa: https://comunidad.movistar.es/t5/Hogar-Fijo-Internet-TV/Puerto-53-Bloqueado-desde-otras-redes/m-p/4170204#M421383